# Get value from onclick object

Tags: jquery, html, hash

I am using **MyApp.updateHashLabel** on using browser location hash to enable back/forward events. This is my html code and one of the buttons (fourth) has got onClick **MyApp.updateApp** with extra value in which I want to parse to another function (article).

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(1, true);" type="button">ONE</button>
    <button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(2, true);" type="button">TWO</button>
    <button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(3, true);" type="button">THREE</button>
    <button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(4, true, four);" type="button">FOUR</button>
</div>
<div id="hash-label">#</div>
<div id="value-label"></div>
<div id="image-placeholder"></div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
MyApp.updateApp = function (hashValue, allowAppToUpdateHash, valueID) {
    var index = parseInt(hashValue, 10);
    var imageNode = document.getElementById('image-placeholder');
    var id = parseInt(valueID, 10);
}
```

And the function is:

```
window.article = function (id) {
    $("#value-label").html(id);
}
```

At the moment I have got an error: ***Uncaught ReferenceError: four is not defined***.
Full code is available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z07cjcpy/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needd to pass it as string

```
<button onclick="MyApp.updateApp(4, true, 'four');" type="button">FOUR</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done it on my jsfiddle and it is not getting it. Says NaN

Comment: @qqruza you just cannt make the string 'four' as number. That is why it throws the error

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button id="four" onclick="MyApp.updateApp(4, true, id);" type="button">FOUR</button>
```

try like this